# How do I find instances of a file in directory/sub-directories in C?

Tags: c, linux

So I have a program, and with a passed filename, I need to find/open all files with that name that exist in the current directory and all sub-directories.

I do not know the names of the subdirectories. I do not care about their names or any other files, I just need to be able to open all files with the passed name.

Thanks!

Comment: For Linux and most other systems, you'd want to use [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html). You can use the `fn` argument to refer to a function that, if the name matches your filename, operates on the file.

Comment: If you want to make it by yourself iterate through directories (`opendir`, `readdir`, `closedir`) and parse the metadata of links (`stat`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with `ntfw()`.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static int display_info(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf){
    char *fileName = "findMe.txt";
    /* fpath holds the full path of the file from the specified starting directory */
    if ( strstr(fpath, fileName) ){
        printf("Match found!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    /* If a starting directory isn't specified, use the current dir */
    if (nftw((argc < 2) ? "." : argv[1], display_info, 20, 0) == -1) {
        perror("nftw");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Of course, you'd validate the return value of `strstr()` to ensure that you're not dealing with _ifindMe.txt_ or _dont_findMe.txt_. :-)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Error checking is indeed important! ...and left out of most of my SO answers :S

Comment: It was merely a comment to inform the OP that the code presented was merely a demonstration of how to use `nftw()` to achieve a simpler goal, not a criticism. :-)